# Magento 2.3 - Does default search suggestion doesn't suggest product names?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

Can anyone tell me what does the default magento 2.3 search suggestion suggests?
Am using default elastic search engine for search.
Can I able to suggest product names?

Comment: So nobody has any solution?

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.3 the default search shown results of recent searched keywords and based on the priority . Priority means the number of time the keyword used for searching . You can see the settings realated to this in Store->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search which will not show product names